# How to connect to schema that is not public with psycopg 2 or 3

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, supabase, psycopg3

I cannot query from other schema's than public, also I am using supabase and connection string provided in supabase doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer. Don't include answers into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `schema.table` in the query.

```py
conn_string = "dbname=postgres user=postgres password=*** host=*** port=****"
with psycopg.connect(conn_string) as conn:
  with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute('SELECT "userId" FROM next_auth.sessions ORDER BY expires DESC LIMIT 1')
    result = cur.fetchone()
```

I am using Supabase and the port that they provided in their "connection string" in the admin panel was wrong.